# The project does not build. The command “esriRegasm.exe …” exited with code -1

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, visual-studio

I want to build the project to create a tool with ArcObjects in Visual Studio. I get this error:

```
The command "esriRegasm.exe "...Project1.dll" /p:Desktop /s" exited with code -1.
```

I use C#, Visual Studio 2015, ArcObjects 10.5, ArcMap 10.5.

To resolve this problem have been made:

- tried to open the solution as an "Adminimtrator" not just a user;
- run the esriRegAsm.exe command from the command line. I tried in two ways. The first, as in the error in Visual Studio. Nothing changes.

[image: picture 1]

Аnd the second, as per the instructions on the help.arcgis website. I get such a fail:

```
Registration failed. The type initializer for 'Project1.Tool1' threw an exception.
```

[image: picture 2]

- tried to open the *.csproj file*, go to the end of the file, find the line *esriRegAsm.exe*, delete it and rebuild the project.

How to build a project? These steps do not help me. I still can't build the project.

Comment: The use of esriRegAsm is depreciated AFIK, it may still work for older projects. Since ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 the developer, who has installed the SDK after installing Visual Studio, uses the new project dialog in Visual Studio and selects Esri tool, populates some metadata and then VS opens a new window which contains all the bits ready to go. After building the project the esriAddIn file is added to ArcGIS using the AddIn manager. Please confirm you are building to x86 and not 'Any CPU' https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ie/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2015